# Update BIOS for Lenovo IdeaPad S145

Tags: lenovo, bios

I read a lot of guides about flashing the BIOS using Linux but unfortunately none of them worked in my case: Lenovo IdeaPad S145.

This is the model and the BIOS file:

https://support.lenovo.com/it/en/downloads/ds506465-bios-update-for-windows-10-64-bit-s145-14iwl-s145-15iwl-v14-iwl-v15-iwl

I unzipped the file and got the `ASCN51WW.exe` file (which is another EXE).

I made a bootable FreeDOS and executing the `ASCN51WW.exe` but I got the error `This program cannot be run in DOS mode`.

I tried unzipping the EXE again and I got those files. How can I proceed? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Well, the file name says "bios-update-for-windows", and it is obviously not a DOS executable. If that file is the only option, a BIOS update will need Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Take out all your hard drives. Put in any blank hard drive (even 64GB), install temporarily any Windows (compatible with the BIOS exe files) and flash. Once flashing completed then reboot. Wait until windows restarts. Once rebooted and all is ok, then shut down and insert old drives with Linux. Don't use Wine or any other emulator for flashing such a critical component like Bios cause you may brick your PC.